# Programmatic access to Ribbon controls in VSTO

Tags: .net, vsto

I am writing C# with VSTO in Visual Studio 2008 in order to create an add-in for Office 2007.

After I have defined a custom ribbon tab using XML, how do I obtain references to the various controls in the Ribbon?  I would like to be able to do things like programatically manipulate the content of an EditBox.

Comment: There's a ton of great information on manipulating the RibbonX interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905530.aspx.

Comment: Generally, one doesn't. You setup 'callbacks' which are invoked on your behalf. Some of these "get" enabled state, "get" the text, or "get" the image, etc.

Comment: random: @mcoolbeth Coolest SO nick ever.

Answer (score 3):

Direct programmatic access to ribbon control properties through callbacks is not possible. However, Visual Studio has a visual ribbon designer that *does* allow direct access. I'll describe both topics below.

When using ribbon callbacks, project code cannot talk to the controls, it can only listen. It's a one-way street, and the code can only wait for `IRibbonUI` to send callback requests for whichever control function was triggered by the user.

The only way to change the properties of a control is to "reboot" it. The proper term for this is `Invalidate`. Either a single control or the entire programmer-defined custom ribbon may be invalidated. This is done with the following two methods:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI.Invalidate() 
Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl(String) '"SomeControlName"
```

The properties of the controls are set when they are first created, or when they are invalidated. Most properties can be set in the `Ribbon.XML` when they are first initialized. Likewise, most properties can be set *when control invalidation is triggered.*

And that's the trick. Well, actually it's the first of two tricks.

When a control or ribbon is invalidated, all of its callbacks are triggered simultaneously; those being `onAction`, `getPressed`, `getImage`, `getLabel`, etc, or specifically for this OP: it's `getText` that asks for the contents of a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox` control, or any of the other controls with textual contents.

And that's the second trick.

The class or module code must keep its own private variables to represent the current values of ribbon control properties. Then when control callbacks are triggered, `IRibbonUI` is essentially asking what the properties should be, and the code should reply back with the desired values.

Voilà!  That's the entire process in a nutshell.

However...as stated above, there's another way: the Ribbon Visual Designer (RVD), which uses Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) as a *wrapper* for everything to do with ribbons. In doing so, it provides the classic "point & doubleclick" technique of creating event handlers which every programmer is accustomed to. It works just like `Windows Forms`. Simply double-click any control in the RVD to be taken directly to that control's `_Click` event in the code. The RVD even adds additional functionality, such as the `Ribbon_Close()` event, which can be used for things like saving the current states of controls.

But there's an important point to make about the RVD: a ribbon will only appear if its `RibbonType` property is set for the application in which it's designed for, *and some of the values are undocumented..!*

The `RibbonType` values follow this general format: `Microsoft.AppName.MainCommandBarName`. The documented values are seen in the drop-down list of the `RibbonType` box of the Properties panel the RVD. Some of the values are:

```
Microsoft.Excel.Workbook
Microsoft.Word.Document
Microsoft.Outlook.Contact 
Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read
```

To have an RVD ribbon appear in any of these apps, one need only start the RVD, set the `RibbonType` property, add controls, and write code for the events. The RVD handles it all; it makes working with ribbons so much easier than `Ribbon.XML`.

But VSTO is only promoted to work with certain Microsoft Office apps, such as Excel, Word, Outlook, etc. I say "promoted" in reference to the "undocumented" part mentioned above. VSTO works with many, *perhaps even all* of the Microsoft Office apps. One need only know the main commandbar name.

Most programmers who've worked with Microsoft Office commandbars and ribbons over the years are probably aware that ribbons grew out of the commandbar system, and adopted some of the same terminology, methods, and values. And every commandbar has a `Name`. This can be seen right in Visual Studio if the commandbar area is right-clicked. There are commandbars for `Debug`, `Build`, `Standard`, and many other purposes. And all versions of Microsoft Office have the VBA editor, which still uses classic commandbars.

That `Name` property is the key to creating ribbons for *any* MSO application, not just the documented ones. The name is what links a ribbon to the window of the application. Most windows have a default commandbar that descended from the originals decades ago, in most cases not seen since Microsoft Office 2003. Well...maybe. I've only tested it with Access. I may take a whack at some of the other apps in the future.

I'll provide an example from a project I'm working on right now: a VSTO Add-In for Word that converted to a VSTO Add-In for Access ([process described here](http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/02/19/vsto-add-ins-for-access/)). The project has an RVD, and the `RibbonType` property is set to `Microsoft.Access.Database`.

Note: The drop-down checklist for `RibbonType` can be tricky. It doesn't like undocumented values. If the keyboard focus tabs through that field and the value is undocumented, it will be deleted. To make it stick, focus must be "clicked-out" by clicking the mouse somewhere else. It may be possible to somehow re-code `Me.RibbonType = ""` in `Ribbon.Designer.VB` to some other syntax, but this may interfere with the normal operation of the designer, and I haven't experimented with it.

I discovered this detail buried in the original code created by the designer for a Visual Studio COM Shared Add-In:

```
'Set up a custom button on the "Standard" commandbar.
Try
    oStandardBar = oCommandBars("Standard")
Catch ex As Exception
    'Access names its main toolbar Database.
    oStandardBar = oCommandBars("Database")
End Try
```

And there it was. Most of the MSO apps have a default toolbar called `Standard`, but for Access it's `Database`. I'd been experimenting with various strings for my Access RVD, but none were working:

```
Microsoft.Access
Microsoft.Access.Application
Microsoft.Access.Application.ActiveWindow
Etc.
```

Then I had a sudden idea and remembered that bit of code from the Shared COM Add-in and tried these:

```
Microsoft.Access.Standard
Microsoft.Access.Database
```

And bingo..! My RVD ribbon magically appeared in Access when I pressed `F5`.

Sorry if this post got long-winded. I hope it may help others.

Comment: Note that the original question here was asked *before* there was a Ribbon Designer...

Comment: Actually, it would help the site more to ask a number of more narrowly targeted questions for which you could compose very specifically-targeted answers. That would break up the "long-windedness" and make the information easier to find/digest for others. On Stack Overflow you are allowed to self-answer.

Comment: Ok, it's hard to sort out the versioning. The original question was asked Mar 25, 2010. I have Visual Studio 2008, and as far as I can tell it's always had the RVD; and it's got designers for MSO 2003 & @007. I checked Add/Remove Programs (it's an XP vm lol), and I have VS 2008 Pro, MSO 2007 Pro, VSTO 2005 2nd Ed, and VSTO Runtime 3. So I'm not sure where the RVD came from. =-S

Comment: As you say, I was thinking about asking/answering my own questions on this topic. As far as I can tell, Andrew Whitechapel
 at Microsoft is the only person to ever mention this, and only twice and buried in VSTO discussions. After I discovered the undocumented RibbonType value for Access, I searched google for the phrase "Microsoft.Access.Database" and his two posts are the only mentions on the entire internet, and one is in a visitor comment on his blog, both linked below:

Comment: The original with visitor comments has since disappeared, and is only visible via Google Cache: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:s-u8wd9PIb8J:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/02/19/vsto-add-ins-for-access/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andreww/ribbon-and-task-pane-in-access-add-ins