# Office Fluent Ribbon callback function to get the current state of a control..?

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I've used VB .Net in Visual Studio to create my first VSTO Addin for Excel. As is common, I had difficulty wrapping my head around the ribbon callbacks. I've gotten them working, but I have a question for which I can't find an answer:

Are there ribbon callback functions to *directly get* the state of a control..?

For instance, to compare ribbons to classes, most of the "clickable" controls trigger the `onAction` callback when they're clicked, and these can be thought of as Events. The multi-state controls such as the checkbox and togglebutton have the `getPressed` callback to set their current state, and these can be though of as the Property Set methods. Similarly, text-based controls have the `getText` callbacks.

But are there any equivalents to the Property Get methods..? Following the inverted nature of callbacks, it seems likely these would be callbacks beginning with `set`, such as `setPressed` or `setText`...but I have yet to find any.

Do they not exist, because of that inverted nature where `get` is actually `set`, and vice versa..?

Comment: Are we discussing Ribbon XML or VSTO's Ribbon Designer?

Comment: Ummm...both? Unless I'm misunderstanding the tools I'm using, the Ribbon Designer is used to generate the XML used by the ribbon..? At least, that's the way I've been using it. I use the RD for the rough layout, export the XML, and then tweak it up with whatever extra properties are needed, such as the attributes for the various callbacks.

Comment: The difference is, working with the Ribbon Designer will do this for you - it makes working with Ribbon controls almost like working with Windows Forms controls. You work with properties and events instead of callbacks. There are no `Set` callbacks in Ribbon XML because there is no event to handle them - a callback needs a trigger. So the "setting" is part of the "get" (and other) callbacks.

Comment: Okay, so I use the RD, and that exports `ribbon.xml` and `ribbon.vb`. Previously I said I tweak the XML, but I neglected to say I also tweak the generated VB file as well. That's where I create the subs and functions for `onAction`, `getPressed`, etc. I also added functionality to handle unrecognized control signatures as well, which has been very helpful. Does any of this sound like what you're referring to? I'm curious about what you describe of working with properties and events instead of callbacks. Could you elaborate on that, or point me to some reading so I could learn about it?

Comment: I'm going to write up an answer as a comment doesn't allow examples very well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSTO Ribbon Designer "wraps" up Ribbon XML so that the developer can work with *basic* controls in a way similar to using Windows Forms controls. This means that properties (attributes in the XML) can be read and written to at run-time, rather than via callbacks. Also, the Ribbon control objects expose *events* rather than the developer needing to code event callbacks.

(Note that for anything more complex, it's necessary to use Ribbon XML. The Designer really only works for basic controls, added from the Toolbox.)

The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019). Below is a small example to demonstrate.

For the example, a `DropDown` control has been added to a Ribbon group, named `DropDown1`. It can be found in the code file `Ribbon1.Designer.cs` where it is declared as

```
internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonDropDown dropDown1;
```

and implemented with

```
// dropDown1
// 
ribbonDropDownItem1.Label = "Item0";
ribbonDropDownItem2.Label = "Item1";
ribbonDropDownItem3.Label = "Item2";
ribbonDropDownItem4.Label = "Item3";
this.dropDown1.Items.Add(ribbonDropDownItem1);
this.dropDown1.Items.Add(ribbonDropDownItem2);
this.dropDown1.Items.Add(ribbonDropDownItem3);
this.dropDown1.Items.Add(ribbonDropDownItem4);
this.dropDown1.Label = "dropDown1";
this.dropDown1.Name = "dropDown1";
this.dropDown1.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler<Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs>(this.dropDown1_SelectionChanged);
```

Note that the information in this file is generated by the "Tools" and is not meant to be edited by the Developer. It can be, but there's no guarantee the "Tools" won't make changes negating any edits. But from it one can see what is executed when the Ribbon is loaded (attribute settings and loading the list) and the creation of an event (which would be a callback in Ribbon XML). All the properties and settings shown are generated using the `Properties` window provided in the Designer, same as for Windows Form controls.

Then a button was added to a Ribbon group (any tab, any group) in the project. Double-click to open the code page in `Ribbon1.cs` with the default `Click` handler and the a code stub was added. The code between the braces is typed by the developer.

Note how this code uses *properties*, which are read (`this.dropDown1.SelectedItem.Label`) and set (`ddItem.Label`). The code shows a message with the caption of the currently selected item, creates a new item, setting the caption and a screen tip, adds it to the dropdown, then selects that item.

```
private void btnSetGetDD1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this.dropDown1.SelectedItem.Label);
    RibbonDropDownItem ddItem = new RibbonDropDownItem();
    ddItem.Label = "new item three added";
    ddItem.ScreenTip = "next test";
    this.dropDown1.Items.Add(ddItem);
    this.dropDown1.SelectedItemIndex = this.dropDown1.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That answer sent me on quite an adventure the past few days. I now consider myself an expert in the Ribbon Visual Designer, lol. I was already familiar with it, but dropped it early on when I found it didn't work with Access. And so I went down the bumpy road of callbacks. But the above link eventually led me to RibbonBase.Close(), and I was like Neo touching the mirror in The Matrix. I'd been doing it completely wrong. After two days of haphazard experimentation, I discovered *undocumented features*, and now I have a VSTO RVD ribbon working in Access Add-In project..!! Thanks..!!

Comment: the undocumented features of which I speak above are documented (at the link below) in another comment I just wrote this morning after this whole process of discovery I went on after reading your answer above (+1!). Again, thanks..!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649984/2705042

Comment: @spinjector Glad it helped - it took quite some time to compose... If I had realized this was for Access I might not have contributed! Now I have to ask: am I answering the question you asked, or did I misunderstand what you asked but stumbled across what you needed :-)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! But indirectly... Your answer inspired me to go off and explore & hack, and that's the best kind of learning. Having the Ribbon Designer working is sooooo much easier than banging my head on callbacks. +1!!

Answer (score 1):

There are no callbacks to get the values of these properties - since you are the one who is setting the various values, you should be the one storing the values internally and thus exposing them both for the ribbon and for your code.

Comment: Ok thank you. I kind of figured the control properties should be cached in code, but I wasn't sure. I thought maybe there was some other aspect of the callback convolution that I was missing.